# "Etwas unter Kontrolle nehmen/bringen/halten"

Tags: phrase

I've encountered three usages of a **unter Kontrolle + verb** construction. Are all three correct? For example:

> Sie haben alles getan, um das Feuer unter Kontrolle zu bringen.

This is a sentence taken from a dictionary. In this sentence, can we use *nehmen* or *halten* instead of *bringen*? If the answer is no, could you please explain why?

Comment: http://dwds.de/?qu=unter+kontrolle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The verb describes what you "do" - therefore *bringen* and *halten* indicate two different concepts.

Let's use a burning house as an example. Extinguishing a fire is more than randomly spraying water on it. It's a process that can take many hours, during which the firecrew stops the fire's expansion and decreases the burning area until the fire is completely extinguished.

- When a house is on fire and the firemen arrive at the scene, their first goal is to make sure the fire does not expand and they can start extinguish the fire in a controlled fashion. They have to **gain control**, in German

  > Das Feuer unter Kontrolle **bringen**.
- During the actual process of extinguishing, they decrease the burning area while making sure that no random sparks or unobserved parts allow for re-ignition or even expansion of the fire, they **keep it under control**, in German

  > Das Feuer unter Kontrolle **halten**.

---

*Nehmen* is rarely used with *Kontrolle*, it would typically be **übernehmen**, which is a switch in responsibility. The full construction is

> die Kontrolle (über *accusative*) (von *dative*) **übernehmen**

In your previous example, a second crew can take over after a certain time. It typically involves some kind of hand-over.

Comment: "Unter Kontrolle nehmen" wird durchaus verwendet. Googletreffer zeigen, dass es Anwendung findet, wenn es darum geht ein Land oder eine Grenze unter Kontrolle zu nehmen.

Comment: @Em1 but definetively the odd one out: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unter+Kontrolle+nehmen%2C+unter+Kontrolle+bringen%2C+unter+Kontrolle+halten&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunter%20Kontrolle%20nehmen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunter%20Kontrolle%20bringen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunter%20Kontrolle%20halten%3B%2Cc0